# Using new FoxH function to solve a trinomial equation. Possible issue?

Tags: functions, numerics, evaluation, special-functions

There is a possible issue on solving the following trinomial equation

$$x^\alpha+x=y$$ for real $x,y,\alpha$. From [Belkic [1]](https://www.researchgate.net/journal/Journal-of-Mathematical-Chemistry-1572-8897/publication/329426799_All_the_trinomial_roots_their_powers_and_logarithms_from_the_Lambert_series_Bell_polynomials_and_Fox-Wright_function_illustration_for_genome_multiplicity_in_survival_of_irradiated_cells/links/5fbe93e7299bf104cf795d90/All-the-trinomial-roots-their-powers-and-logarithms-from-the-Lambert-series-Bell-polynomials-and-Fox-Wright-function-illustration-for-genome-multiplicity-in-survival-of-irradiated-cells.pdf), it is known that for $\alpha>1$ a solution is found using the Confluent Fox-Wright Function as

$$x = y\cdot\,_{1}\Psi_{1}([1,\alpha];[2,\alpha-1];-y^{\alpha-1})$$ It is also known the relationship between the generalized Fox-Wright and Fox-H functions. (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function)). For this particular case we have $$\,_{1}\Psi_{1}([1,\alpha];[2,\alpha-1];-y^{\alpha-1})=H_{1,2}^{1,1}([(0,\alpha)];[(0,1),(-1,\alpha-1)];y^{\alpha-1})$$ $$\,_{1}\Psi_{1}([1,\alpha];[2,\alpha-1];-y^{\alpha-1})=H_{2,1}^{1,1}([(1,1),(2,\alpha-1)];[(1,\alpha)];y^{1-\alpha})$$ Translated to Wolfram language, the first equation can be written as (I am not sure if I am missing something)

**$x=y\cdot$FoxH[{{{0,$\alpha$}},{{}}},{{{0,1}},{{-1,$\alpha$-1}}},$y^{\alpha-1}$]**

but if I try to compute it numerically, for instance for either $\alpha=2, y=1$ or any other  numerical values, it returns unevaluated. Any help on this subject is welcome. This is the example code

```
 FoxH[{{{0, 2}}, {}}, {{{0, 1}}, {{-1, 1}}}, 1]
```

---

**Update**

I have initiated a discussion on Wolfram's Community [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2435180) which we can summarize as follows.

Inverse Functions for trinomial equations expressed as **FoxH[]** functions return unevaluated under Wolfram's Mathematica v12.3-v13.0 and this is currently a checked software's issue.

However if real parameter $\alpha$ is rational there is a solution whenever denominators are not big enough. In these cases **FoxH[]** functions can be converted into hypergeometric **MeijerG[]** functions that are properly evaluated in Mathematica.

In the mentioned Wolfram's Community Discussion, there is an alternative code provided by Mariusz Iwaniuk (a user of this Mathematica SE blog) that solves such problem for rationals $\alpha$ using  MeijerG.

Also, [this link](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FoxHToMeijerG/) provides the function **FoxHToMeijerG[]** by Jan Mangaldan (noticed by Mariusz as well) that allows to work symbolically for all (positive or negative) $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$\{0}. For instance

```
y*FoxHToMeijerG[FoxH[{{{0, \[Alpha]}}, {}}, {{{0, 1}}, {{-1, \[Alpha] - 1}}}, 
y^(\[Alpha] - 1)] /. \[Alpha] -> 2]
```

Returns `1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 y])` that gives the golden ratio if $y=1$

[1](https://www.researchgate.net/journal/Journal-of-Mathematical-Chemistry-1572-8897/publication/329426799_All_the_trinomial_roots_their_powers_and_logarithms_from_the_Lambert_series_Bell_polynomials_and_Fox-Wright_function_illustration_for_genome_multiplicity_in_survival_of_irradiated_cells/links/5fbe93e7299bf104cf795d90/All-the-trinomial-roots-their-powers-and-logarithms-from-the-Lambert-series-Bell-polynomials-and-Fox-Wright-function-illustration-for-genome-multiplicity-in-survival-of-irradiated-cells.pdf) Dževad Belkic."All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from
the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright
function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of
irradiated cells". Journal of Mathematical Chemistry (2019) 57:59–106
https://doi.org/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3

Comment: Can you, please, provide the code that you have used, formatted to be copy and pasted so that others can help you?

Comment: See [How to copy code](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I think you've got too many braces: An empty liist is `{}`, not `{{}}`, as in `FoxH[{{{0, 2}}, {}}, {{{0, 1}}, {{-1, 1}}}, 1.]`. However, it's taking forever to calculate. :/

Comment: @Michael_E2 that's right. I have asked in Wolfram Community such FoxH behavior. There is an example in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoxH.html solving all roots of $x^n-x=y$ for $n$ a positive integer (a slightly different polynomial equation) by means of FoxH but this function has two pairs of parameters more compared to the relationships between $\,_{1}\Psi_{1}$ and $H^{1,1}_{1,2}$ or $H^{1,1}_{2,1}$ shown above.